# How to getOrElse with another Option in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option, partial-functions

Let's assume that we have an option `foo1` and an option `foo2`:

```
val foo1: Option[Foo]
val foo2: Option[Foo]
```

Is there an operator/function that allows me to return the value of the `foo2` when `foo1` is `None`?

```
val finalFoo: Option[Foo] = foo1.getOrElseOption(foo2)
```

The above `getOrElseOption` does not exist obviously. I know we can do sth like this, but it is somewhat verbose and hard to understand:

```
foo1.map(Some(_)).getOrElse(foo2).
```

Comment: [orElse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option.html#orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B])

Comment: What about [`orElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Option` works a bit like a partial function, so `orElse` will do what you want:

```
foo1 orElse foo2
```